# Glassfish EJB Timer Service issues with Read-Only or Locked Derby Database

Tags: installation, glassfish, ejb, derby

I have two Solaris servers, each with a new installation of Glassfish 3.1.1 (Build 12) and Java 1.6.0_27. The Glassfish servers appear to be fully functional, except I am unable to deploy applications that leverage the EJB Timer Service.  By default the Timer Service depends on a table, "EJB_*TIMER*_TBL", created within the default "__TimerPool" Connection Pool to store state information.  On one server the error is:

java.sql.SQLException: An SQL data change is not permitted for a read-only connection, user or database.

On the other server, the error is:

ERROR 40XL1: A lock could not be obtained within the time requested

I had believed the issue was file permissions related.  However I have reviewed the file permissions & ownership of the Java and Glassfish installation, including the derby database files under "domains/domain1/lib/databases/ejbtimer" and they are the same as on other Solaris servers where I have not had this issue.

**Do you have any ideas what would cause the Derby database to be either 'read-only' or 'locked' in a fresh installation of Glassfish & Java?**  I recognize there may be two different causes here, but both appeared at the same time, following the same installation steps on two separate servers.

Here are more portions of the stack traces from the Glassfish server.log:

Locked Stack:

> [#|2011-10-07T17:35:21.739+0000|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5108:Unable to initialize EJB Timer Service. The possible cause is the timer resource is not configured correctly, the database has not been started, or the timer database table has not been created.
>   javax.ejb.EJBException
>     at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5193)
>     at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5091)
>   ...
>
> Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: A lock could not be obtained within the time requested
>   Error Code: 30000
>   Call: SELECT "TIMERID", "APPLICATIONID", "BLOB", "CONTAINERID", "CREATIONTIMERAW", "INITIALEXPIRATIONRAW", "INTERVALDURATION", "LASTEXPIRATIONRAW", "OWNERID", "PKHASHCODE", "SCHEDULE", "STATE" FROM "EJB_*TIMER*_TBL" WHERE (("OWNERID" = ?) AND ("STATE" = ?))
>     bind => [2 parameters bound]
>   Query: ReadAllQuery(name="findTimersByOwnerAndState" referenceClass=TimerState sql="SELECT "TIMERID", "APPLICATIONID", "BLOB", "CONTAINERID", "CREATIONTIMERAW", "INITIALEXPIRATIONRAW", "INTERVALDURATION", "LASTEXPIRATIONRAW", "OWNERID", "PKHASHCODE", "SCHEDULE", "STATE" FROM "EJB_*TIMER*_TBL" WHERE (("OWNERID" = ?) AND ("STATE" = ?))")
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:333)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:644)
>   ...
>
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: A lock could not be obtained within the time requested
>     at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
>     ... 95 more
>   Caused by: ERROR 40XL1: A lock could not be obtained within the time requested
>     at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.derby.impl.services.locks.ConcurrentLockSet.lockObject(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.derby.impl.services.locks.ConcurrentLockSet.zeroDurationLockObject(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.derby.impl.services.locks.AbstractPool.zeroDurationlockObject(Unknown Source)
>   ...

Read-Only Stack:

> [#|2011-10-07T18:35:43.498+0000|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=20;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
>   javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted
>     at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5120)
>   ...
>
> Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.
>     at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:479)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:852)
>     at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5114)
>     ... 65 more
>   Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: An SQL data change is not permitted for a read-only connection, user or database.
>   Error Code: 20000
>   Call: INSERT INTO "EJB_*TIMER*_TBL" ("TIMERID", "APPLICATIONID", "BLOB", "CONTAINERID", "CREATIONTIMERAW", "INITIALEXPIRATIONRAW", "INTERVALDURATION", "LASTEXPIRATIONRAW", "OWNERID", "PKHASHCODE", "SCHEDULE", "STATE") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>     bind => [12 parameters bound]
>   Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.sun.ejb.containers.TimerState@75d8af)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:324)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:840)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:906)
>   ...
>
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: An SQL data change is not permitted for a read-only connection, user or database.
>     at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
>   ...

Answer (score 6):

I had the same situation with the same error message (`Error Code: 20000 Call: INSERT INTO EJB__TIMER__TBL ...`) mentioned above (I was not able to deploy ear package using EJB timers) so I have checked my running

`glassfish_directory_domains/my_domain/lib/databases/ejbtimer` directory.

And I have seen one important thing in this directory after listing it's content: somehow the `db.lck` file was created under root (perhaps last time I started the domain using sudo accidentally) so I did chown and chgrp for all files in this directory and their subdirectories (of course glassfish domain was stopped during this work).

After that everything was perfect again. My `ear package` deployed successfully.

Thanks for the cooperative thinking :-)

Answer (score 1):

Derby databases can be read-only because they have been installed on read-only media such as CD-ROMs. They can also be read-only because they are stored in a jar or zip file and accessed directly from that jar/zip. Here's some more information: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/devguide/cdevdeploy15325.html

Comment: This derby database was not read only.  It was the embedded on withing Glassfish.  On one system we changed the timers to use a different database other than Derby.  On another we seemed to have this issue with persistent timers (the default).  We changed them to not be persistent and have not had an issue with the timers running on a Derby database since.  Fortunately we did not need them to be persistent.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the same stacktrace. The problem was caused by the glassfish admin password. I had to change it to apply a ssl certificate. After I changed the password the error message occured.

I solved the problem by resetting the glassfish password.

[Remove password examples](http://smoumie.blogspot.de/2014/01/reset-glassfish-password-solved.html)